# Why is my inline JS breaking my div size?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

When I draw a div and set background-color, it works perfectly.

```
<div style="border:1px solid #f00; background-color:#00f;width:{{...
```

When I try to make the colour a dynamic inline JS value (I use a fixed inline value for simplicity here) then the whole div collapses to 2 pixels high & wide.

```
<div style="border:1px solid #f00; background-color:#{{ "00f"}};width:{{...

test:#{{ "00f" }}
```

`test:#00f` displays correctly afterward. Why does my div collapse? I use dynamic values for width and it loves it fine

Comment: Wow this is confusing... Why are you using {{}} in the style? Can you show us your whole code?

Answer (score 0):

The [ngClass](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass) directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added.

```
<!-- whatever is typed into this input will be used as the class for the div below -->
<input type="text" ng-model="textType">

<!-- the class will be whatever is typed into the input box above -->
<div ng-class="textType">Look! I'm Words!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the dynamic styles with angularJS would be with ng-class as Amit has mentioned in the first answer. However, it is always better to handle ng-class based on angular variable values as below:

```
<div ng-class="{ '00f-background': awesome, 'normal-background': simple }
```

In this case, 00f-background class is set if awesome is true and normal-background is set if simple is true.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was pretty basic, the double quote " in the tags {{ ... }} should be a single quote ' apparently - at least, it works if the string is surrounded as single quotes. It was breaking the style element completely which is why the div was shrinking to zero size.

```
<div style="border:1px solid #f00; background-color:#{{ '00f'}};width:{{...
```

works correctly. appreciate the suggestions about using the model properly - but that's somewhat philosophical for this question which was specifically why the div was breaking with that use of inline.